# What exactly is the [tips] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

After reading [Re-evaluating [tips] and tip-like questions](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1470/9498) and the [tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips) questions, I determined that we currently use [tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips) for two things: code-golfing questions, and language creation questions.

Regarding non code-golfing tip questions, wouldn't it be better to drop the [tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips) tag because [tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips) seems to be used for tips on how golf better?

However, most questions tagged [tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips) are also tagged [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf). This does not make sense, as:

1. The [code golf tag wiki](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/code-golf/info) makes it seem that the question is a challenge, which it is not
2. This seems to make [tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips) a meta tag

However, it seems logical that [tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips) could be used for other tips, such as tips for writing answers to [fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code), [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill), etc.

What should [tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips) be? Should it be [golfing-tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/golfing-tips)? If so, we could create [fast-code-tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fast-code-tips), etc. Or, should we just keep on tagging [tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips) with [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) only? Or should we increase its range to all of the primary winning criteria ([code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), [fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code), [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill), [code-bowling](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-bowling), etc)?

Comment: I'd go for using two tags, (tips + challenge-type), even if the tag wikis for the challenge types don't seem to fit that purpose. If we're starting to create cartesian products of concepts as tags that really defeats the tag system.