# Post other people's code?

Tags: discussion, policy, answers

Some people are very good code golfers but for their own reasons do not want to join PPCG. Is it acceptable to post their solutions as answers to challenges?

If at all acceptable, I would personally do so only as Community Wiki and only with full reference to the original author and their code. I would also fully explain the code to the best of my ability.

Comment: I personally think it should be allowed. Actually, I've done so once in the past (and just edited it to a Community Wiki after reading your question). Someone posted an amazing Whitespace quine on his/her own website, and since quines in Whitespace are neither easy nor was one already posted in the _Golf you a quine for great good!_ challenge, I decided to [post it with explanation back in April](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/162391/52210). As long as you credit the original creator (and make sure that their copyright rules allow it), I don't see any harm in posting it as a PPCG answer.

Comment: I think it's a good idea. My [most popular challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/172036/yeah-but-no-but-yeah) was based entirely on a script written in jest by a friend. I think it would be advisable to ask the original author of the script before posting it, but I don't think it should be disallowed by our rules if the author allows it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As long as you're legally allowed to post the code, I see no reason why PPCG would forbid this. Since we're talking about your friend, you might want to double-check they're OK with licensing their work under cc by-sa 3.0.

I personally wouldn't mark the answers as community wiki, especially if you wrote the explanation yourself. See [How should Community Wikis be used?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9688/12012)